# Dashboard pattern does't display properly in album orientation

Tags: android, user-interface, dashboard

I'm trying to implement DashboardLayout ([Pattern 3](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/twitter-for-android-closer-look-at.html)). 
All ok when orientation is portrait:
[image]

But when orientation of app changes to album it looks like:
[image]

Here is the source code of [DashboardLayout.java](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java?r=27a82ff10b436da5914a3961df245ff8f66b6252)

Activity layout file as in example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.ui.DashboardLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/posts"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_db_posts"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="posts" />

    ***and four same buttons***

</com.example.ui.DashboardLayout>
```

`style/DashboardButton`:

```
<style name="DashboardButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/db_buttons</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    </style>
```

Background only for button pressed state:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/db_button_bd_pressed" />

</selector>
```

Pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <padding 
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="20dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="20dp" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <solid android:color="#a6cee1" />

</shape>
```

Where is the problem? Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dashboardlayout just works if the number of buttons is even. You have an odd number, just insert an extra button with:

```
android:background="@null" or "#ffffffff"//transparent
```

So it will handle it like a extra button but it is transparent.

Comment: Just a minute ago, I thought of the same thing. Thanks for your solution.